# Casting arrays to specific types in Swift

Tags: swift

Say I have two arrays:

```
var exterior: Array<(name: String, value: (code: Code, pass: Bool))> = []
var interior: Array<(name: String, value: (code: Code, type: Type, pass: Bool))> = []
```

I have a UISegmentedControl that, depending on which segment is selected, will show data from the respective array. To reduce boilerplate, I'd like to use one fuction for setup:

```
func build(section: Section) {
    var data: Array<Any>

    switch section {
    case .Exterior:
        data = exterior
    case .Interior:
        data = interior
    }

    for i in 0...data.count - 1 where i % 4 == 0 {
        for y in i...i + 4 {
            guard y < data.count - 1 else {
                break
            }
            switch section {
            case .Exterior:
                let v = data as! Array<(String, (Report.Code, Bool))>
                // Do stuff here...
            case .Interior:
                let v = data as! Array<(String, (Report.Code, Report.Type, Bool))>
                // Do stuff here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This won't work since I cannot cast to an array that holds `Any`. If I change the type of both `interior` and `exterior` to `Any` and try casing them to their respective types, I get an error: `can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes`. What are my options in this situation?

Comment: Since the difference of both array types is only the `type` parameter, wouldn't it be more efficient to declare the type parameter as optional? The benefit it you have one common type for both arrays and you can identify `exterior` by the `nil` type. In Swift  using `Any` is always the worst, worst habit if a more specific type (at least `AnyObject`) can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast `Array<Any>` to `Array<AnyOther>`, because there is no inheritance between `Array<Any>` and `Array<AnyOther>`. You should actually *convert* such arrays like so:

```
let xs: [Any] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let ys: [Int] = xs.flatMap { $0 as? Int }
print(ys.dynamicType) // Array<Int>
print(ys) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```