# Cannot convert value of type '[SomeStruct]' to specified type '[SomeProtocol]'

Tags: ios, swift

Here is some setup code to explain what is happening:

```
protocol CanJump{
    func jump()
}

struct Dog: CanJump{
    func jump(){
        print("yay jump")
    }
}

struct Cat: CanJump{
    func jump(){
        print("nothx")
    }
}

let d = [Dog()]
let c = Cat()
```

This does not work:

```
let thingsThatCanJump: [CanJump] = d
```

> Cannot convert value of type [Dog] to specified type [CanJump]

This does work:

```
let thingsThatCanJump: [CanJump] = [c]
```

A disgusting workaround that I've come up with is:

```
let thingsThatCanJump: [CanJump] = d.map({$0 as CanJump})
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

I'm guessing this has something to do with the compiler not completely evaluating types and conformance.

Comment: FYI: let d = [Dog() as CanJump] works a s well

Comment: It's a consequence of the fact that generics are invariant in Swift. [See this Q&A for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any). Although note that you only encounter this problem with an array of structs, not classes.

Comment: @originaluser2: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that @originaluser2 already answered this question. You can see their detailed explanation here:

[Why isn't [SomeStruct] convertible to [Any]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening as you `let d` is actually type of [Dog] and swift is quite strict about type safety.

This fix this you can do following:

```
let d: [CanJump] = [Dog()]
```

Hope this helps