# Swift downcasting array of objects

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation

class A: NSObject {

}

class B: A {

}

let array = [B(),B(),B(),B()]

array as? [A] //this does not works

B() as? A // this works
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this?  You can pass an array of `B` to anything that expects an array of `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as?` is a conditional *downcasting* operation (which can fail, and therefore returns an optional) – and you're trying to *upcast* (which can never fail, and therefore you can do freely).

You therefore can just use `as` in order to freely upcast the array – or rely on type inference, as Casey notes.

```
let arrayOfB = [B(),B(),B(),B()]

let arrayOfA = arrayOfB as [A] // cast of [B] to [A] via 'as'

let explicitArrayOfA : [A] = arrayOfB // cast of [B] to [A] via inference of explicit type 

func somethingThatExpectsA(a:[A]) {...}

somethingThatExpectsA(arrayOfB) // implicit conversion of [B] to [A]
```

Although the compiler's error of `A is not a subtype of B` is certainly unhelpful in the context. A more suitable error (or maybe just a warning) could be `'as?' will always succeed in casting '[B]' to '[A]' – did you mean to use 'as'?`.

You should also note that for your example:

```
B() as? A // this works
```

You'll get a compiler warning saying `Conditional cast from 'B' to 'A' always succeeds`. Although *why* you get a compiler warning, rather than error for this – I can't say. I suspect it's due to the [special way in which array casting happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any).

Answer (score 1):

Because B is an A, you can drop the conditional cast and

```
let thing = array as [A]
```

Or declare the destination as the desired type and forget about casting

```
let thing : [A] = array
```