# How to make extension to protocol using associatedtype and array

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols, extension-methods, associated-types

Say I have these protocols

```
protocol Actionable {

}

protocol M: class {
    associatedtype Action: Actionable
    var views: [Action] { get set }
}
```

and two functions

```
func f(view: Actionable) {

}

func g(views: [Actionable]) {

}
```

And I extend the protocol `M`

```
extension M {
    func add(view: Action) {
        views.append(view)
        f(view)
        g(views)
    }
}
```

When I call `f(view` it works. But when I call `g(views)` it shows error

> Cannot convert value of type '[Self.Action]' to expected argument type '[Actionable]'

Here `g` accepts an array instead of a single object like `f`. Why does array matter in this case? How to work around this?

As a side note, this seems to be the kind of error for generic struct, too

```
protocol Actionable {

}

struct M<T: Actionable> {
  var views: [T]
}

func g(views: [Actionable]) {

}

extension M {
  func add() {
    g(views)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of the fact that arrays in Swift have limitations with the types they can implicitly converted to – which is a consequence of the invariance of generics in Swift, which I discuss further [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any).

One possible solution is to use `map` in order to convert each element individually from `Action` to `Actionable` (the elements can be freely up-cast, but the array itself cannot):

```
extension M {
    func add(view: Action) {
        views.append(view)
        f(view)
        g(views.map{$0})
    }
}
```

However in your specific situation, I would simply recommend making your `f` and `g` functions generic in order to maintain the concrete type that you supply to them (unless you specifically want them to be type-erased):

```
func f<T:Actionable>(view: T) {
    ...
}

func g<T:Actionable>(views: [T]) {
    ...
}
```

```
extension M {
    func add(view: Action) {
        views.append(view)
        f(view)
        g(views)
    }
}
```

Now the generic type of `Action` will be maintained when you call them, providing you with better type-safety if you want to pass the argument around.