# Why is filter unable to convert an array of structs to an array of a protocol type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have the following code:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var string: String {get}
}

struct TestStructOne : TestProtocol {
    let string = "test string"
    var stringTwo = "test string three"
}

struct TestStructTwo : TestProtocol {
    let string = "test string two"
}

var testStructOnes = [TestStructOne(), TestStructOne(), TestStructOne()]

// works
var protocolArrayOne: [TestProtocol] = [TestProtocol]()
for testStruct in testStructOnes.filter({ $0.stringTwo == "test string three" }) {
    protocolArrayOne.append(testStruct)
}

// does not work, cannot copnvert value of type '[TestStructOne]' to specified type '[TestProtocol]'
var protocolArrayTwo: [TestProtocol] = testStructOnes.filter({ $0.stringTwo == "test string three" })
```

I don't understand why the last line doesn't work. Can anybody fill me in? I don't see how it is different than iterating through the array and manually adding each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a limitation of Swift arrays when it comes to implicitly converting their type, which is a consequence on the invariance of generics in Swift, and is discussed more [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any/).

The key to the solution is as you cannot convert the array directly from `[TestStructOne]` to `[TestProtocol]` – instead you have to convert each element separately, which is why your method of using a for loop and manually appending the elements to a new array worked.

The simplest way to solve this problem with functional programming is usually through using `map` in order to allow each element to get up-cast to `TestProtocol` (Swift can infer this from the explicit type annotation):

```
let protocolArrayTwo: [TestProtocol] = testStructOnes.filter {
    $0.stringTwo == "test string three"
}.map{$0}
```

However, in your case this is inefficient as you're having to iterate through your array twice, which incidentally is also what your `for` loop is doing (filtering and then looping over the elements).

Instead, you could use a `for` loop with a given `where` condition in order to filter out the elements you want by appending them to a new array in a single iteration:

```
var protocolArray = [TestProtocol]()
for testStruct in testStructOnes where testStruct.stringTwo == "test string three"  {
    protocolArray.append(testStruct)
}
```

Or if you like functional programming, you could use `flatMap` in order to both filter out the elements you don't want (by taking advantage of the fact that `flatMap` filters out `nil`) and transforming them to your protocol type:

```
let protocolArray : [TestProtocol] = testStructOnes.flatMap {
    $0.stringTwo == "test string three" ? $0 : nil
}
```

Much like the `map`, the explicit type annotation here will allow `flatMap` to implicitly convert each element individually to your `TestProtocol`.