# Swift initialise empty array to store different structs later

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a couple of different types of structs (Promo & Event). I'd like to create an empty array which gets populated with an array of each type depending on the outcome of an `if` statement.

So something like this:

```
var dataArray:[Any] = []  // see options I've tried below 

if myTest == true {
    dataArray = [Promo, Promo, Promo]
} else {
    dataArray = [Event, Event, Event]    
}
```

I have tried using:

```
1. var dataArray: [Any] = []
2. var dataArray: [AnyObject] = []
3. var dataArray: [Any] = [Any]()
4. var dataArray: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
```

but when I try to store an array of `Promo` Structs in `dataArray` I get an error `Cannot assign value of type '[Promo]' to type '[Any]'` etc.

So, how do I initialise an array so that it can store a variety of (unknown) Structs. Or how do I modify my Structs to enable them to be stored in an array?

I'm really struggling to see what I'm doing wrong so any pointers would be v. helpful.

---

Here are my Structs:
**Promo.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct Promo {

    // initialise the stored properties for use later
    let promoId : Int
    let date : NSDate
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let busName : String
    let busId : Int
    let categoryId: Int
    let featured: Bool

    // a universal init() method which has optional parameters
    init(promoId: Int,
         date: NSDate,
         title: String,
         body: String,
         busName: String,
         busId: Int,
         categoryId: Int,
         featured: Bool
        ){
        self.promoId = promoId
        self.date = date
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.busName = busName
        self.busId = busId
        self.categoryId = categoryId
        self.featured = featured
    }
}

// allow us to compare structs
extension Promo: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: Promo, rhs: Promo) -> Bool {
    return lhs.promoId == rhs.promoId
        && lhs.date == rhs.date
        && lhs.title == rhs.title
        && lhs.body == rhs.body
        && lhs.busName == rhs.busName
        && lhs.busId == rhs.busId
        && lhs.categoryId == rhs.categoryId
        && lhs.featured == rhs.featured
}
```

**Event.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct Event {

    // initialise the stored properties for use later
    let eventId : Int
    let date : NSDate
    let title: String
    let body: String
    let busName : String
    let busId : Int
    let categoryId: Int

    // a universal init() method which has optional parameters
    init(eventId: Int,
         date: NSDate,
         title: String,
         body: String,
         busName: String,
         busId: Int,
         categoryId: Int
        ){
        self.eventId = eventId
        self.date = date
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.busName = busName
        self.busId = busId
        self.categoryId = categoryId
    }
}
```

Comment: In the example you're not assigning the structs to dataArray, rather the type. Did you mean to use dataArray = [Promo(), Promo(), Promo()], etc instead?

Comment: Yes, @CaseyFleser that's actually what's assigned (I get an array of Promo structs returned from a function). Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't \[SomeStruct\] convertible to \[Any\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to assign to `dataArray` from `[Promo]` or `[Event]` arrays, you could `map`:

```
var dataArray:[Any] = []
var promoArray:[Promo] = [Promo(), Promo(), Promo()]
var eventArray:[Event] = [Event(), Event(),Event()]

if myTest == true {
    dataArray = promoArray.map { $0 as Any }
} else {
    dataArray = eventArray.map { $0 as Any }
}
```

Or create new `Any` arrays:

```
if myTest == true {
    dataArray = Array<Any>(arrayLiteral: promoArray)
} else {
    dataArray = Array<Any>(arrayLiteral: eventArray)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Casey I used a slightly modified version of your first .map snippet which works great. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure thing, happy to.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you intended, but you can make this a bit cleaner by using classes instead of structs.  It appears that a 'Promo' is just an 'Event' with one extra data member (featured)... If that's the case, then you can rename the Promo.promoId field Promo.eventId, and then make it a subclass of Event.  Like this:

```
class Promo : Event {
    let featured: Bool

    // a universal init() method which has optional parameters
    init(eventId: Int,
         date: NSDate,
         title: String,
         body: String,
         busName: String,
         busId: Int,
         categoryId: Int,
         featured: Bool
        ){
        self.featured = featured
        super.init(eventId: eventId, date: date, title: title, body: body, busName: busName, busId: busId, categoryId: categoryId)
    }
}
```

Then just create the data array like this:

```
var dataArray = [Event]()

if myTest == true {
    dataArray = [promo1, promo2, promo3]
} else {
    dataArray = [event1, event2, event3]
}
```

To use the featured member for a Promo you'll still need to cast like this:

```
if let thisPromo = dataArray[0] as? Promo {
    print(thisPromo.featured)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve - I did wonder about that but this is a simplified version for SO. There are actually 4 structs with pretty different members (I just copied Events & Promos as they're the shortest :-) I like your idea though and am always keen to simplify things so will give it some thought.