# How to create a new array with arrays of different classes

Tags: swift

I have 2 classes, both are subclass of `SuperClass`:

```
class A: SuperClass {
    ...
    static let arrayA: [A] = [a, b, c]
}

class B: SuperClass {
    ...
    static let arrayB: [B] = [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Then I want to create a new array of type `SuperClass`:

```
let newArray: [SuperClass] = A.arrayA + B.arrayB
```

> Here I got an error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Guessing | try this: `let newArray: [SuperClass] = [A.arrayA, B.arrayB]`

Comment: @Mr.UB that'll create a new array with 2 elements of arrayA and arrayB

Comment: What is your expected result/output if you `print(newArray)`?

Comment: @Mr.UB an array like [a, b, c, 1, 2, 3] without modifying arrayA and arrayB's values.

Comment: @BrightFuture , What is the value of A? is this matrix problem?

Comment: @MohanSingh no it's not, just an ordinary array of a normal class

Comment: @MohanSingh what confused me was, why was it not allowed to add arrays of 2 subclasses to an array of the super class

Comment: @BrightFuture , Okay i will answer it

Comment: @BrightFuture , ouch Is my answer not compatible with you?

Comment: @MohanSingh yeah actually when I did it that way I got an error, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124615/discussion-between-mohansingh-and-bright-future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Posting something i tried on my desk:

```
class User:NSObject{
    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(n:String, a:Int) {
        self.name = n
        self.age = a
    }
}

class Section: User {
    static let arrayA: [Section] = [Section(n: "John", a: 20), Section(n: "Mariah", a: 18)]
}

class Library: User {
    static let arrayB: [Library] = [Library(n: "Martin", a: 20), Library(n: "Mariah", a: 18)]
}
```

Finally:

```
let newArray:[User] = Section.arrayA.map { $0 as User } + Library.arrayB.map { $0 as User }
print(newArray)
```

Output:

```
(lldb) po newArray
▿ 4 elements
  - [0] : <TestSwift2.Section: 0x7fdb4b43d460>
  - [1] : <TestSwift2.Section: 0x7fdb4b43d4e0>
  - [2] : <TestSwift2.Library: 0x7fdb4b43e4b0>
  - [3] : <TestSwift2.Library: 0x7fdb4b43e4e0>

(lldb) po newArray[0].age
20

(lldb) po newArray[0].name
"John"
```

Comment: I would be wary of using `map(_:)` here, as converting from `[Library]` or `[Section]` to `[User]` should be an O(1) operation, whereas `map(_:)` is O(n) – see [my comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39783764/how-to-create-a-new-array-with-arrays-of-different-classes#comment66871732_39788833).

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert each array from types `[A]` and `[B]` to type `[SuperClass]`. This is best done with `map`. Then you can combine them.

```
class SuperClass : CustomStringConvertible {
  var description: String { return "super" }
}
class A: SuperClass {
  let value: String
  init(_ value: String) { self.value = value }
  static let arrayA: [A] = [A("a"), A("b"), A("c")]
  override var description: String { return "\(value)" }
}

class B: SuperClass {
  let value: Int
  init(_ value: Int) { self.value = value }
  static let arrayB: [B] = [B(1), B(2), B(3)]
  override var description: String { return "\(value)" }
}

// convert each array to [SuperClass] and combine them
let newArray: [SuperClass] = A.arrayA.map { $0 as SuperClass } + B.arrayB.map { $0 as SuperClass }

print(newArray) // -> "[a, b, c, 1, 2, 3]\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that because generics are invariant in Swift, without any compiler magic, not even this would compile:

```
let newArray : [SuperClass] = A.arrayA
```

as you're attempting to convert an `Array<A>` to an `Array<SuperClass>`, which are entirely unrelated types (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188580/why-isnt-somestruct-convertible-to-any)).

Although, for some native collection types in Swift (`Array` being one of them), the compiler *does* do some magic which allows for implicit conversions between collections with elements of a subclass type to those with elements of a superclass type (as well as concrete types to abstract types that they conform to).

However, when it comes to this line:

```
let newArray : [SuperClass] = A.arrayA + B.arrayB
```

it's simply too much for the compiler to resolve, as it both has to locate the correct `+` overload for the context, which could be any of the following:

```
public func +<C : RangeReplaceableCollection, S : Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == C.Iterator.Element>(lhs: C, rhs: S) -> C
public func +<C : RangeReplaceableCollection, S : Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == C.Iterator.Element>(lhs: S, rhs: C) -> C
public func +<RRC1 : RangeReplaceableCollection, RRC2 : RangeReplaceableCollection where RRC1.Iterator.Element == RRC2.Iterator.Element>(lhs: RRC1, rhs: RRC2) -> RRC1
```

and it has to infer that you want the element type for both `A.arrayA` and `B.arrayB` to be converted to `SuperClass`.

In order to help it, you could simply cast both sides to `[SuperClass]`:

```
let newArray = A.arrayA as [SuperClass] + B.arrayB as [SuperClass]
```

or do:

```
let newArray : [SuperClass] = A.arrayA as [SuperClass] + B.arrayB
```

Or (the most interesting solution), you could define an overload for `+` that deals specifically with two `Array<T>` operands:

```
func +<T>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> [T] {
    var lhs = lhs
    lhs.reserveCapacity(lhs.count + rhs.count)
    lhs.append(contentsOf: rhs)
    return lhs
}
```

<sup>(this has a similar implementation to the existing [standard library overloads](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb#L1105))</sup>

Now this works:

```
let newArray : [SuperClass] = A.arrayA + B.arrayB
```

From what I can tell, the compiler only has a problem when the generic constraint for the element types of the operands to be equal is secondary (i.e as a `where` clause). This overload however has it as its primary constraint.

Comment: Note that when it comes to expressing the conversion explicitly, I would advise doing `as [SuperClass]` rather than `map {$0 as SuperClass}` in this case. This conversion should be O(1), as the memory structure of the array should remain unchanged (only the static type has to change). `map` on the other hand is an O(n) operation (although the compiler may well be able to optimise this, I did some benchmarking in an optimised build and it didn't seem like it was able to be optimised to the same level as doing `as [SuperClass]`).