# How does AnyHashable appear to automatically box values?

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

Swift 3 introduced `AnyHashable`, which is a type-erased box around a Hashable. It solves the problem of how to store objects of different types that conform to the same protocol when the protocol requires an associated type.

When creating an `AnyHashable` box, you have to provide the thing you want to box in the initializer:

```
let someHashable: AnyHashable = AnyHashable(1)
```

However, you can also use AnyHashable as if you were using a protocol without actually creating anything. It's as if Apple overloaded the assignment operator to do automatic boxing:

```
let someHashable: AnyHashable = 1
```

My question is, how is this possible? I have followed several of the guides online about how to create my own type-erased boxes. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/breaking-down-type-erasures-in-swift/
However it seems that there is something else going on with the way Apple is doing it.

If it was simply a type-erased box, you would still need to provide the type somewhere, like so:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: Hashable {
    let someHashable: AnyHashable<T>
}
```

Otherwise the compiler would complain: `"requires arguments in <...>"`.
Yet I can simply create a variable:

```
let someHashable: AnyHashable
```

I ask because I am implementing a delegate that uses an associated type. I created a type-erased box for it, however I'd like to hide the fact that there is type-erasure going on underneath (similar to the way `AnyHashable` appears to work).

Here is my implementation (ignoring the requirements for `weak` properties for now).

```
// The delegate protocol

public protocol SomeDelegate {
    associatedtype T
    func doSomething(_ t: T)
}

// Type-erasure boilerplate

fileprivate class _AnySomeDelegateBase<T>: SomeDelegate {

    init() {
        guard type(of: self) != _AnySomeDelegateBase.self else {
            fatalError("Must subclass")
        }
    }

    func doSomething(_ t: T) {
        fatalError("Must override")
    }

}

fileprivate final class _AnySomeDelegateBox<SD: SomeDelegate> : _AnySomeDelegateBase<SD.T> {

    private var concrete: SD

    init(_ concrete: SD) {
        self.concrete = concrete
    }

    override func doSomething(_ t: T) {
        self.concrete.doSomething(t)
    }

}

// Type-erasure wrapper

public final class AnySomeDelegate<T>: SomeDelegate {

    private let box: _AnySomeDelegateBase<T>

    public init<SD: SomeDelegate>(_ base: SD) where SD.T == T {
        self.box = _AnySomeDelegateBox(base)
    }

    public func doSomething(_ t: T) {
        self.box.doSomething(t)
    }

}
```

And here is how I'd like to use it:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: AnySomeDelegate?

}
```

But this won't work: `AnySomeDelegate requires arguments in <...>`. Which means I'd also have to parameterize the `UIViewController` around `T`.

```
class MyViewController<T>: UIViewController {

    var delegate: AnySomeDelegate<T>?

}
```

Comment: The `AnyHashable` auto-conversion is special-cased by the compiler, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42021207/2976878

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite a duplicate – it doesn't really answer the second part of your question. Really the auto-conversion is orthogonal to whether a generic placeholder is required or not. In your case, you kind of really the generic placeholder `T` on your type-erasing wrapper. Why? Because what would you type erase it to? `Any`? Well then you'd have `doSomething(_: Any)` that would have to forward onto implementations that take subtype arguments, e.g `doSomething(_: Int)`; and that can't work unless you type cast and silently fail (or crash) if you pass an incorrectly typed argument.

Comment: The type erasure for `Equatable`'s `==` works nicely because if the wrong typed arguments are passed, it can return `false`, because well they're not equal. Your protocol doesn't express that kind of semantic.

Comment: Btw, you can often simplify these kinds of type erasers with closures – see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/43264274/2976878, which achieves a similar goal as `AnyHashable`. [Rob Napier has also written a good article on type erasers](http://robnapier.net/erasure).