# no exact matches in call to instance method 'append'

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm creating Native Module for React Native. I'm trying to process the data in Swift, here's the function

[image]

```swift
func getCornerPoints(_ cornerPoints: [AnyHashable]?) -> [AnyHashable]? {
    var result: [AnyHashable] = []
    
    if cornerPoints == nil {
      return result
    }
    for point in cornerPoints ?? [] {
      guard let point = point as? NSValue else {
        continue
      }
      var resultPoint: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
      resultPoint["x"] = NSNumber(value: Float(point.cgPointValue.x))
      resultPoint["y"] = NSNumber(value: Float(point.cgPointValue.y))
      
      result.append(resultPoint) // error is here "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'"
    }
    return result
  }
```

Comment: @vadian okay. it's answer my question to change  `Any` to `NSNumber`

but, how if the value is not only `NSNumber`

```swift
var linesElements: [AnyHashable] = []

for line in lines {
  var l: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
  l["text"] = line.text
  l["cornerPoints"] = getCornerPoints(line.cornerPoints)
  linesElements.append(l)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Any` does not conform to `Hashable` therefore `[AnyHashable: Any]` (variable resultPoint) cannot be represented by `AnyHashable`.

But why is the value of resultPoint `Any` at all? It's clearly `NSNumber`.
If you declare resultPoint

```
var resultPoint: [AnyHashable: NSNumber] = [:]
```

then the code compiles.

And why is the return type optional? `result` is – also clearly – non-optional

Comment: Note that [Swift implicitly converts to `AnyHashable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021207/how-are-int-and-string-accepted-as-anyhashable). So it doesn't matter that “`[AnyHashable: Any]` is not equal to `AnyHashable`”. It only matters that `[AnyHashable: Any]` does not **conform** to `Hashable` (because `Any` does not conform to `Hashable`).