# Swift - Generic not able to append to array of super class

Tags: swift

Ok here's the problem:

say we have a parent class that holds an array of ChildClasses

```
class ParentClass {

    var list: [ChildClass<UITableViewCell>] = []

    func append<T>(cell: T) where T: UITableViewCell {
        let child = ChildClass<T>()
        list.append(child)
    }

}
```

and the child class

```
class ChildClass<T> where T: UITableViewCell {

    var obj: T!

}
```

both of the classes are generic and the Type(T) is alway of the type UITableViewCell

now if you try to build it you'll get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type ChildClass< T > to expected argument type ChildClass< UITableViewCell >

but if the T is a subclass of UITableViewCell, shouldn't it be able to convert the T???
thanks in advance

Comment: Strongly related (dupe?): [How do I store a value of type Class<ClassImplementingProtocol> in a Dictionary of type \[String:Class<Protocol>\] in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38590548/2976878)

Comment: it's really hard to find that question, still if you think it's duplicate, i agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChildClass<T>` is not a subclass of `ChildClass<UITableViewCell>`, even if `T` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

My answer here provides an example of what can go wrong if such a covariance was established: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615736/3141234

Comment: Ok, but how can I store items with different type of the same subclass in a list with generics??

Comment: You have to define child as `ChildClass<UITableViewCell>()`, and assign `cell` to its `obj`. Note of course, that this upcasts the `cell` to be `UITableViewCell`, losing type information.

Comment: so I will lose the type information and I have to add additional cast for it to work. well guess you are right, thanks anyway

Comment: @MohsenShakiba Yup, there's no way around that. As Sweeper pointed out, `ChildClass<UITableViewCell>` is a completely unrelated type to ChildClass<SomeSubclassOfUITableViewCell>`

Comment: I've voted up both, but which one of the answers do you think deserves the mark??

Answer (score 1):

Swift is very strict with generics. `ChildClass<UITableViewCell>` is not compatible with `ChildClass<SomeSubclassOfUITableViewCell>`.

One workaround for this is to convert the `ChildClass<SomeSubclassOfUITableViewCell>` to `ChildClass<UITableViewCell>`, since logically, they should be compatible. I also noticed that you have not used the `cell` parameter, so maybe this is how you want your method to be:

```
func append<T>(cell: T) where T: UITableViewCell {
    let child = ChildClass<UITableViewCell>()
    child.obj = cell
    list.append(child)
}
```